# What is the limitation of iteration in executer.thread()

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi

This loop is could run upto 2000 times.... Is there any limitation of using multithreading ?

```
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            for index, unique_product in enumerate(scenario_unique_products):
                kpis_data = [sku for sku in all_products_data if sku.scenario_product_id == unique_product.id]
                products_length = len(kpis_data)

                results = []
                future = executor.map(self.filterProductBasicInformation, [all_sku_basic_information, all_sku_g2n_percent_delta_data], [count, count], [count+products_length, count+products_length])
                for r in future:
                    results.append(r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is without limit, you still use only four threads in pool, but you generate other and other tasks for processing.

Only size of memory will be your limit.

Comment: Even the size of memory may be no limit if the four worker threads are able to process the given tasks faster than the client is able to supply them.